# Is there a better way to wait for a user action when doing Async promises?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am new to Vue.js and have been trying to do the following:

Basically, I have a component `PopUp` that can be shown and hidden using functions of the same name.

I want it so that `popUp.show()` returns a promise and that promise is a response object that contains how the user closed the popUp (button press, clicking outside the popup etc...)

The main problem I'm facing is how to wait for the information on how the popUp is closed. At the moment I am thinking of using a loop but this seems very wrong as it can stall the whole program.

So initial thought was to do something like:

```
async show() {
  //Insert Show PopUp code
  return this.resolve()
}

hide() {
  //Insert hide code
  this.closed = true;
}

resolve() {
  while(!this.closed){}
  //insert build response object code
  return response
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to wait for a change in a variable perhaps rather than using a loop.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you need to have promises here. You just want to know the status when the modal closes, that will depend on the modal library you used.

Comment: Did you try to create and return the Promise (not resolved) in show, and resolve it when hide() is called ?

Comment: Well, you must have event handlers that are thrown when the user closes the popup (the button click event, the click event outside the modal, etc.). So resolve the promise when those events occur...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the input I got from this question I solved it in the following way using the skeleton above as a template:

```
show() {
  //Insert Show PopUp code
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const responder = (bdy: Response) => {
        resolve(bdy);
      };
      resolve = responder;
    });
}

hide() {
  //Insert hide code
  resolve();
}

private resolve() : void
```

Comment: Notice that this may result in pending promises in case show and hide calls don't match.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the `show()` function should return a Promise, then listen for 'click' events. When the click is on the right element (close button, outside of the dialog), call the resolve function.

Pattern looks something like this:

```js
function show() {

  // immediately return a Promise
  return new Promise((resolve) => {

    // click responder
    const responder = (evt)  => {
      let target = evt.target;

      // remove listener and resolve when a dialog-closing
      // element is clicked
      if (target === one_of_the_dialog_closing_elements) {
        document.removeEventListener('click', responder);
        resolve(target);
      }
    };

    // set up the click listener
    document.addEventListener("click", responder);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A loop is a step in the wrong direction because it loads CPU. `closed` could be watched with `$watch` but it's unknown if it's reactive and this is also unnecessary.

The only ways `closed` is changed should be `hide` and `show` calls, then this can be solved like:

```
show() {
  if (this._resolvePopup)
    this._resolvePopup(); // handle multiple show() calls

  return new Promise(resolve => this._resolvePopup = resolve);
}

hide() {
  this.closed = true; // read-only in view
  if (this._resolvePopup) {
    this._resolvePopup();
    this._resolvePopup = null;
  }
}
```